# POI 3.7 set mergedranges's border but the foregroundcolor replaced all

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I tried to create another `CellRangeAddress`, but the style still replaced by `mergedrange1`.
But the border is drawed.

Code:

```
    mergedrange = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange);
    mergedrange1 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange1);
    mergedrange2 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange2);
    mergedrange3 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange3);
    mergedrange4 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange4);
    mergedrange5 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange5);
    mergedrange6 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange6);
    mergedrange7 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange7);
    mergedrange8 = drawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange8);
    mergedrange9 = redrawMergeRegionBorder(wb,lotReportSheet,mergedrange9);
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
private CellRangeAddress drawMergeRegionBorder(XSSFWorkbook wb,XSSFSheet lotReportSheet, CellRangeAddress mergedrange) {
    CellRangeAddress cra = mergedrange;
    RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN, cra, lotReportSheet,wb);
    RegionUtil.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN, cra, lotReportSheet,wb);
    RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN, cra, lotReportSheet,wb);
    RegionUtil.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN, cra, lotReportSheet,wb);
    return cra;
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what you exactly mean? its very unclear atm

Comment: mergerange~mergerange4 are the same color of foreground, others is not.

Comment: still unclear. describe exactly what you are currently having, and exactly, what you want to have

Comment: chinese is the worst idea to explain something on an english platform...

Comment: I found the soulution is merge the regions first, or the style will cover every region, thanks